# GUI SSH for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ssh

My question is simple. Is there any ssh client in ubuntu 14.04 that has GUI. I need it to remotely access website files and update them.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is either VNC over SSH (which shows the desktop of the other computer on your computer) or `sshfs` (which mounts a directory on the other computer in one of your folders). The latter may be more helpful to you.

Comment: What I always use is my local editor with a `sftp://user@host/home/myuser/myfile` path to access the files remotely and edit them. (SFTP is file access over SSH, enbaled by default in most OpenSSH installations.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most advanced Linux file managers are able to use SFTP (the SSH file transfer protocol), along with Ubuntu's default called **Nautilus**

In Nautilus, you can use *File → Connect to Server...* in order to connect to remote file systems using various protocols, including SFTP, FTP, FTPS and SMB.

Enter the necessary information (server address, user and password might be asked when connectiong) and the remote access will be mounted temporarily in your system, until you unmount it again.

Answer (score 6):

FileZilla is a full-featured FTP/FTPS/SFTP client with an easy-to-use GUI.

```
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

- Supports FTP, FTP over SSL/TLS (FTPS) and SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)
- IPv6 support
- Available in more than 40 languages
- Supports resume and transfer of large files >4GB
- Easy to use Site Manager and transfer queue
- Bookmarks
- Drag & drop support
- Speed limits
- Filename filters
- Directory comparison
- Network configuration wizard
- Remote file editing
- Keep-alive
- HTTP/1.1, SOCKS5 and FTP Proxy support
- Logging to file
- Synchronized directory browsing
- Remote file search
- Tabbed interface to connect to multiple servers

[image]

<sub>sorry for German text</sub>

Comment: You can start programs (at least those which support it) with another language (read: in English) using  `env LANG=en_US.UTF8 program-to-execute`, or any other language code than en_US